# Where can I get PGNs of FIDE rated tournaments?

Tags: fide, pgn

FIDE requires tournament organizers of high level tournaments (basically tournaments which are strong enough that norms can be won) to submit the pgn files of games played in the tournament to FIDE. Amongst other things this allows FIDE to check for cheating and other abnormalities.

Where can I download such pgn files?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately they don't make available a central respository where you can download all the pgns they have for, say, October 2022. If that is what you want then the closest thing is "[The Week in Chess](https://theweekinchess.com/)" where you can download one pgn file of all the games played where their pgns have become available in the last week. This should include the high level FIDE games but it will also contain lots of other games as well which may not be the same quality.

On the FIDE "[Tournament List](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml)" website you have to download one tournament at a time and you first have to find your tournament. On the [initial page](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml) you first have to choose your federation from the drop down list and click "go". This gives a list of tournaments registered with FIDE for the current month which is not quite what you want. Now you need to scroll to the bottom of the page where you can select the period from another drop down list and again click on "go".

For instance [here is the list](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ENG) of current tournaments in England. If I want to see tournaments played in October 2022 I need to go to the bottom of the page and select "November 2022" from the drop down and click "go". This is because tournaments played in October will be reported in November. Doing this gives [this list](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ENG&rating_period=2022-11-01). Not all tournaments have pgn files. The ones that do have a brown icon on the left hand side of the page. Clicking on this icon gives the option to either view the pgn files or download it.

Here is the form of the URL for tournaments in England in October - https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ENG&rating_period=2022-11-01. This can be customised if you want to speed-up / automate the process. Change the "ENG" part in "country=ENG" to select another federation. Change the "2022-11-01" part in the "rating_period=2022-11-01" to change the reporting period.

Additionally every such tournament has an "event code". If you know the event code then you can go directly to the pgn page for that event. For instance "2022 4NCL GM Norm Invitational (Hull)" has event code "294631" and so the [direct access url](https://ratings.fide.com/view_games.phtml?event=294631) for that tournaments pgn page is https://ratings.fide.com/view_games.phtml?event=294631.

Finally, if you want to just download the pgn file for a tournament for which you know the event code then it looks like this - https://ratings.fide.com/view_pgn.phtml?code=294631&download=1.

Comment: The [archive page](https://ratings.fide.com/archive.phtml) has options for country and month-year. Chess.com (requires an account, free account will do), pgnmentor, and chessbase also have good pgn collections.

Comment: sometimes chessresults also has games

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brian's answer, the chessbase online database is also quite good - it's thorough and easily accessible. The games can be found at https://database.chessbase.com/, and also by pressing the 'enter' key when inside a game in the chessbase software.

Answer (score 0):

For many high-level tournaments, the game pgns are available in [chessgames.com](https://www.chessgames.com/). Very often after passing some time, top-level tournaments such as wcc are available in single pgn files.

Premius members of chessgames.com can download multiple games from a tournament (or games of a player from different tournaments) in a single pgn file.